# Event object is undefined on JavaScript addEventListener function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a `switch` selection based on an `HTML` select with the following code:

```
document.getElementById("filterList").addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
        switch(evt.options[evt.selectedIndex].value) {
            case "priceAsc":
                sortAndShowProducts(ORDER_ASC_BY_PRICE, currentProductsArray);
                break;
            case "priceDesc":
                sortAndShowProducts(ORDER_DESC_BY_PRICE, currentProductsArray);
                break;
            case "nameAsc":
                sortAndShowProducts(ORDER_ASC_BY_NAME, currentProductsArray);
                break;
            case "priceAsc":
                sortAndShowProducts(ORDER_DESC_BY_NAME, currentProductsArray);
                break;
            default:
                console.log("Selección inválida: " + evt.options[evt.selectedIndex].value);
                break;
        }
    });
```

And the HTML tag:

```
<select name="selectFilter" id="filterList" class="browser-default custom-select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione el filtro...</option>
    <option value="priceAsc">Precio ascendente</option>
    <option value="priceDesc">Precio descendente</option>
    <option value="nameAsc">Nombre(A-Z)</option>
    <option value="priceAsc" value="nameDesc">Nombre(Z-A)</option>
</select>
```

But when I select and option, I get the following message in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "undefined", evt.options is undefined
    <anonymous> http://192.168.1.115/proyectojap/js/products.js:95
```

Comment: thats not the issue but - You are not meant to have two `values` in one option. or is that a typo ?

Comment: Add `target` between `evt` and `options` like this `evt.target.options`.

Comment: The two values are a mistake. Thanks @AlwaysHelping, you solved my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) on both `evt.target.options` and `evt.target.selectedIndex` to get the selected `option` value. In addition, you can also use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) as well to have the same results

Also, you can **not** have two value `attributes` in one option. You had `two` values in your last `option`.

**Live Demo:**

```js
document.getElementById("filterList").addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value)
  /*  switch (evt.target.options[evt.target.selectedIndex].value) {
     case "priceAsc":
       sortAndShowProducts(ORDER_ASC_BY_PRICE, currentProductsArray);
       break;
     case "priceDesc":
       sortAndShowProducts(ORDER_DESC_BY_PRICE, currentProductsArray);
       break;
     case "nameAsc":
       sortAndShowProducts(ORDER_ASC_BY_NAME, currentProductsArray);
       break;
     case "priceAsc":
       sortAndShowProducts(ORDER_DESC_BY_NAME, currentProductsArray);
       break;
     default:
       console.log("Selección inválida: " + evt.options[evt.selectedIndex].value);
       break;
   } */
});
```

```html
<select name="selectFilter" id="filterList" class="browser-default custom-select">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione el filtro...</option>
  <option value="priceAsc">Precio ascendente</option>
  <option value="priceDesc">Precio descendente</option>
  <option value="nameAsc">Nombre(A-Z)</option>
  <option value="priceAsc">Nombre(Z-A)</option>
</select>
```